# File reloading Background thread vs Request based

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, berkeley-db

I'm building a web service which serves requests from an embedded database which is essentially a file. The file is periodically replaced by another process.

The service has to detect this change and update the file reference. Is it better to make that request driven i.e. each request checks if a newer version is available or have a background thread to do so?

Comment: What is your requests' volume? How are you accessing the file? Flat file? Json, Xml?

Comment: 5k/s; Pipe separated key value pairs in text file

Comment: you would need to perform some sort f if-modified-since with every request and cache the data when appropriate.  Or another  thread inside the servlet/controller picking up changes. If the updates are not too frequent you may get by without a thread. But 5k per second seems to call for something robust. Asynchronous response would be nice

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do anything IO related on every request. As a matter of fact, I would argue that the service itself should not be responsible for checking the freshness of the data. All it should care about is lookingup the data from the source (perform some business logic that is not cpu intensive) and emit it out in order to be within the safe bounds of SLAs for a real time web application (i assume?). You could consider possibilities like:

- Background threads (as you had mentioned) which are pollers that keep
  checking and updating the file.
- An event based design (pub-sub) that notifies your app to update whenever there is a trigger that is fired on changes to the file
  content.

Comment: "I wouldn't do anything IO related on every request." Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be  like background process Which will notify the subscriber for register event.You can use file listener for this purpose.Below example is a poll based model.

```
 WatchService watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();

    Path dir = Paths.get("Path/To/Watched/Directory");
       dir.register(watcher, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_DELETE, ENTRY_MODIFY);
```